# C, I get printing out random numbers (not address) instead of scanned number

Tags: c, scanf

I got the next code and for the first 6 scans in the loop its works just fine but in the 7th time its changes one of the numbers in the Array to `313***` (where `*` is random number). if I continue scanning numbers its still made this error once in 4-6 scanning.

Anyone know what that means?

```
int* take2(int num){
            static int size=0;
            int i,mid;
            static int* arr;
            if (size==0){
                 arr = (int*)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
                if (!arr) {
                    printf("ERROR! Not enough memory!\n");
                    exit(1); 
                }
                size=1;
                arr[0]=num;
            }
            else {
                size++;
                arr = (int*)realloc(arr, size*sizeof(int));
                if (!arr) {
                     printf("ERROR! Not enough memory!\n");
                    exit(1); 
                }
                for (i = 0; i<size; i++ ){
                     if (arr[i]<num){
                     swap(&num,&arr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            mid=size/2;
            printf("the middle number is: %d\n",arr[mid]);
            for (i = 0; i<size; i++ ){
              printf(" ,%d",arr[i]);
            }
            return arr;
    }
```

the main is:

```
void main(){
    int flag1=1;
    int num1;
    int *arr1;
    while(flag1){
      printf("\n enter a number: \n if you want to exit press -1\n");
      scanf("%d" ,&num1 );
      if (num1==-1) break;
      arr1=take2(num1);
    }
    free(arr1);
}
```

when I run this function (in the main I scanning for numbers in loop..) i get after 7 numbers the next output:(this output is after 7 scanning)

```
the middle number is: 3
 ,6 ,5 ,4 ,3 ,2 ,1
 enter a number:
 if you want to exit press -1
7
the middle number is: 4
 ,7 ,6 ,5 ,4 ,3 ,2 ,31361
 enter a number:
 if you want to exit press -1
```

Comment: first replace scanf to fgets. scanf is not a safe function.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that `realloc` does not initialize the memory (where `calloc` does) and that's where the junk comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
            size++;
            arr = (int*)realloc(arr, size*sizeof(int));
            if (!arr) {
                 printf("ERROR! Not enough memory!\n");
                exit(1); 
            }
            for (i = 0; i<size; i++ ){
                 if (arr[i]<num){       // arr[size-1] has indeterminate value
                 swap(&num,&arr[i]);
                }
            }
```

After `realloc` you access the whole array but you have never written to the new element. Remember that `realloc` leaves new memory with indeterminate values.

Maybe you miss a

```
arr[size-1] = num;
```

before the loop

Comment: thanks, 
the accurate code I entered is    arr[size-1]=0;
I had to make it 0 so the IF in the loop will be able to change it.